# Makefile VV=$(shell cat foo.txt) causes VV command not found

Tags: file, makefile

He, 
I want to read the contents of a file (which contains relative file paths) to a variable and prefix every line in the file with a path. Then copy all those files to a directory.
Like this:

```
$(httpd_DIR)/my.tar: $(mypath)/html.txt
    rm -rf web
    mkdir -p web
    VV = $(addprefix $(httpd_DIR)/, $(shell cat $(mypath)/html.txt) )
    cp -R $$VV $(httpd_DIR)/web
    $(TAR) -C $(httpd_DIR) -cvf $(httpd_DIR)/web.tar web
```

The $(mypath)/html.txt file contains a list of relative file paths like this:
dir1/file1.html
dir2/file2.html
dir3/file3.html

For some reason I get the followin error:
/bin/bash: VV: command not found

I'm not trying to execute VV, so why is het giving me this error?
 Note that if I uncomment the cp command, I still get the same error...
I'm using GNU make on a linux PC.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here.

```
VV = $(addprefix $(httpd_DIR)/, $(shell cat $(mypath)/html.txt) )
```

You haven't told us what shell you're using, so I'll assume bash.

If you want to assign a variable in bash, you must beware whitespace: `VV=foo` is legal and will do what you expect, but if you type `VV = foo`, the shell will interpret the first word, "VV", as a command, and balk. If you type `VV=foo bar`, the shell will assign `foo` to `VV`, then balk at the command `bar`. You can use `VV="foo bar"` instead.

Then you run into another problem. Each command runs in its own subshell, so variables assigned in one command don't survive to the next:

```
VV=foo
echo $$VV # this will echo a blank
```

You must combine the commands, like this:

```
VV=foo ; echo $$VV # this will echo foo
```

or this:

```
VV=foo ; \
  echo $$VV # this will echo foo
```

(Note that there is only one TAB there, before the first line.)

**In general, you should test these constructs with the simplest commands you can think of, before you plug in the real commands.** That way it's much easier to catch these bugs.

Comment: Nicely explained. Another problem is that the commands don't create the target file. As written, the commands update web.tar, not my.tar.

Comment: @Idelic: good point. I usually don't notice bugs like that until I introduce automatic variables (which is the next step in the improvement of this makefile).

Comment: He, Thanks a lot for this info, it is _really_ helpful! I'll also check out automatic variables.